# Postcode restriction in checkout page

Tags: product, checkout

On my stores checkout page, I need customers to be able to provide their postcode/zip code and the system to either restrict or apply a small charge for certain postcodes.

is there such a feature built in for magento? And what is the best way to go about implementing this?

Comment: you can use `magento table rate shipping method` , you can check this link for more information.  https://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento default Table rate shipping method, you can check below link for more information :

https://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/